# How is CVE-2015-0235 triggered and exploited?

Tags: c, security, memory, exploit

I'm looking at some of the case studies and exploitations on the security advisory for CVE-2015-0235 (http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2015/q1/274) and I can't figure out some of the details. Sorry if it's immediately obvious.

In the vulnerability test, he generates a string of length:

```
size_t len = sizeof(temp.buffer) - 16*sizeof(unsigned char) - 2*sizeof(char *) - 1;
```

This string length causes the size checks to pass as he mentioned in the Analysis portion when solving for `strlen(name)` from a `size_needed` size temp buffer:

```
85       size_needed = (sizeof (*host_addr)
86                      + sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) + strlen (name) + 1);
```

However, in the case studies when he tries several programs, he uses this string length:

```
[user () fedora-19-32b ~]$ /usr/sbin/clockdiff `python -c "print '0' * $((0x10000-16*1-2*4-1-4))"`
```

I'm guessing the `0x10000` comes from the default buffer size when the non-reentrant `gethostbyname` is called. `16*1` is from `sizeof(unsigned char)`. `2*4` is from `sizeof(char *)` on a 32-bit machine. The `1` is for the null terminator. Where does the `4` come in? It seems like he's subtracting the size of a pointer but wouldn't this cause the string to fit correctly into the temporary buffer? The vulnerability is because `size_needed` left out `sizeof (*h_alias_ptr)`.

Also in the exploitation section, he describes overwriting the `size` field of the `malloc` chunk:

```
struct malloc_chunk {

  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

  /* Only used for large blocks: pointer to next larger size.  */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};
```

However, because of the limitation of only overflowing by 4 bytes (on a 32-bit machine), how is he able to reach `size`? Wouldn't `prev_size` be all he's able to reach?

Answer (score 1):

GHOST.c calls gethostbyname_r(): the buffer you'll overflow and its EXACT size in memory are caller-supplied. The few bytes you'll overflow will directly overwrite whatever follows the buffer (canary, in GHOST.c).

clockdiff calls gethostbyname(): the buffer you'll overflow is malloc()ated, and its REAL size in memory includes an extra size_t (size, in struct malloc_chunk) and maybe some padding (request2size(), in malloc.c). The mysterious 4 bytes you're talking about make sure there is no padding at all (otherwise the few bytes you'll overflow might overwrite the padding and nothing else).